# soundcloud http request search engine

Tags: php, xml, http, request, soundcloud

I want to retrieve XML data from soundcloud using a simple search engine, that retrieves results in a simple results table array

```
$tracks = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=".$var."&client_id=bbba84be29098bdaad6a5de1c048e3e9&limit=10";

$mysongs = simplexml_load_file($tracks);

echo "<table>";
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
echo '<tbody>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>State</th> <th>Name</th><th>Song</th><th>artist</th><th>user</th>   <th>user</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody>';
foreach ($mysongs->track->user as $track) {
echo '<tbody>';    
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo '</td>';
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $user->kind;
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
 echo '</tbody>';
}
```

this is my code but nothing seems to display as a result, i have tested the same format of code on another api (yelp) and it does work in xml, so what am i missing here? i dont want to use json, i need it to be xml ( the user -> kind ) is just for testing the code right now.

Comment: Why there is a space between ? and q .. `tracks?    q=`

Comment: corrected, my mistake

Comment: if you post on your browser this https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=rock&client_id=bbba84be29098bdaad6a5de1c048e3e9&limit=10, it will retrieve some data in xml, but im not able to retrieve this info to php. thats my problem.Im trying to use request http from soundcloud, but it returns blank, i dont know if im missing something.

Answer (score 0):

the variable $user doesn't exist.  the variable you want is $track. so where you have 
    echo $user->kind
replace that with 
    echo $track->kind

you can see the format of the returned object (and it's hierarchy by running the code in the cli and 
    print_r($mysongs)

Comment: made the change you suggested, but still returned blank

Comment: did you look at the returned object with var_dump or print_r.  each track may not have a 'user' section - I found this while testing your code. I had to guess at what to set $var to but when set to 'genesis' I got 10 tracks, but no user section.